# Am not able to insert data into database using ajax laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

> I am trying to take amount from the html tags and store the amount into database but the about here
> ajax code is not working and data is not stored in the database. And how to know if ajax code is redirected it's control to the laravel controller

```
@include('layouts.students.header')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
<body>
<div class="col">
<p class="text-right" style="font-size: 18px;">
<i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><strong 
class="amount">299</strong>
</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-right">
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg 
buy_now">Proceed</button>
</div>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
$('button').click(function(event){
e.preventDefault();
var amount = $('.amount').html();
$.ajax({
url : '{{route('razorpay')}}',
method : 'POST',
dataType : 'jason',
data : {amount :amount * 100},
success : function (Response) {
console.log(Response);
}
});
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

controller :
public function dopayment(Request $request)
{
$data = $request->all();
$result = Payment::insert($data);
echo "inserted";
}
```

Comment: did you check your browser console are there any error ?

Comment: There is no error in the console

Comment: "not working" isn't a useful description of your problem. Instead please do some debugging and narrow down the issue and give us a specific description of the behaviour of your program

Comment: I just want to insert the amount 299 which is a text in strong tag in database but the value is not  inserted in the database.

Comment: Yes. But you need to be more specific. Narrow down the problem. Look for errors, look for where the code starts not to do what you expected. Do you understand how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

In ajax method can you use `dataType : 'json',` instead of `jason`

Comment: If you check your network tab, are you seeing the request leaving the frontend and what is the response in the network tab of console?

Comment: Good to hear. What was the problem?